# What is the proper "subject" for an email in which I want to ask a question about a paper from its author?

Tags: email

I want to ask a question regarding an issue in a paper I recently read. The author of the paper is an academic who may receive lots of emails daily.
I want to choose a proper subject for my email that is as short as possible. I have come with these ideas for the subject:

- question
- question?
- a question about your paper
- a question about paper xxx

Are there any better suggestions that are in common usage? I want my email to be formal and polite to persuade him to read and answer my question.

Comment: A question about "title". Or just: "Title". Why is this something that needs asking? There is no secret magic set of words.

Comment: "question" and "question?" are, in almost all cases, not a helpful subject line for any email.

Comment: If this is a recent paper you might get better results by naming the conference/journal: E.G. "Your ABCD2017 paper"

Comment: Carefully proofread the email before sending it too, as you're misusing some words here (e.g. witch and audible). The pronoun "I" is always capitalised in English, as is the first letter of any sentence. (I think a grammatically correct email is more likely to get a response.)

Comment: [Question regarding your paper "Insert title here."] usually suffices. Try to capitalize where necessary. You may add adjectives sensibly if you want to grab attention. I.e. *important* question, *urgent* question, *recent* paper, *very interesting* paper, etc.

Comment: @Co3O4 When I see "attention grabbing" adjectives in email subjects, my first reaction is "spam".

Comment: @JeffE Operative word being sensible.

Comment: I do this from time to time to call an author's attention to a salient Stack Exchange question and encourage them to answer, with good success. The subject lines I choose are short and use *key technical terms* found within the paper in question. Then you have like the first half of the first sentence in the body to reassure them you are not a crank and your message is worth reading. Put your effort there.